# If / else in Django View

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to display a different template depending on a condition:

```
class RouteList(ListView):
    model = DailyRoute
    template_name = 'route_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        if DailyRoute.objects.filter( stage = '1').exists():
            query_set = DailyRoute.objects.filter(owner=employer, stage = '1').order_by('route')

        else:
            query_set = []

        return query_set
```

If True - go to template 1.html
If False - go to template 2.html

The above works for template 1.html only. I can't figure out how properly use the if/else statements to return the correct template and query_set for True/False. Feeling like a dope on this one.

Comment: Maybe you can use `get_template_names()` method: https://docs.djangoproject.com/ko/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can override `get_template_names`, use `cached_property` for single query to the db

```
from django.utils.functional import cached_property

class RouteList(ListView):
    model = DailyRoute
    template_name = 'route_list.html'

    @cached_property
    def stage_exist(self):
        return DailyRoute.objects.filter( stage = '1').exists()

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.stage_exist:
            query_set = DailyRoute.objects.filter(owner=employer, stage = '1').order_by('route')
        else:
            query_set = DailyRoute.objects.none()
        return query_set

    def get_template_names(self):
        return ['template 1.html'] self.stage_exist else ['template 2.html']
```

and read all comments, they are useful

Answer (score 0):

`get_queryset()` should return a `QuerySet` object, so the solution is to return an empty `QuerySet`, which you can do with the [none() function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#none).

So returning `DailyRoute.objects.none()` should do it for template 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sending nothing to the template, then you might as well use `HttpResponseRedirect` to redirect to template2 when condition is met.